# Self-Referencing Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I can't figure out why I can't cast a self-referencing generic.

In Java, I have a self-referencing generic. There are a bunch of *things* (`Intent`s), and strategies for looking up (resolving) those things (`ResolutionStrategy`s).

The self-referencing `Intent` type is defined below. I want, at compile time, to define classes that can only receive a `ResolutionStrategy` that accepts the same intent.

```
public interface Intent<I extends Intent<I, R>, R extends Resolution>
{
    void resolve(ResolutionStrategy<I, R> strategy);

    R getResolution();
}
```

Resolution strategy is thus:

```
public interface ResolutionStrategy<I extends Intent<I, R>, R extends Resolution>
{
    R resolve(I intent);
}
```

So when I'm operating on a list of these `Intent`s, I don't really care what they are. However, I do want to create particular types that represent a concrete thing in my domain model. Here's an example:

```
public class OrgIntent implements Intent<OrgIntent, IdentifiableResolution>
{
    public final String name;

    public OrgIntent(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(ResolutionStrategy<OrgIntent, IdentifiableResolution> strategy)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public IdentifiableResolution getResolution()
    {
        //Return resolution got from strategy at some point in the past
        return null;
    }
}
```

`IdentifiableResolution` is a simple and uninteresting implementation of `Resolution`.

All good so far. The plan is then to build a nice graph of these `Intent`s, then iterate over them, passing each to a `ResolutionStrategyFactory` to get the relevant strategy for resolving them. However, I can't cast `OrgIntent` to anything generic enough to add to a list!

```
private <I extends Intent<I, R>, R extends Resolution> DirectedAcyclicGraph<Intent<I, R>, DefaultEdge> buildGraph(Declaration declaration) throws CycleFoundException
{
        DirectedAcyclicGraph<Intent<I, R>, DefaultEdge> dag = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
        // Does not compile
        Intent<I, R> orgIntent = new OrgIntent("some name");
        // Compiles, but then not a valid argument to dag.addVertex()
        Intent<OrgIntent, IdentifiableResolution> orgIntent = new OrgIntent("some name");
        // Compiles, but then not a valid argument to dag.addVertex()
        OrgIntent orgIntent = new OrgIntent("some name");

        //Then do this
        dag.addVertex(orgIntent);
        ...
```

Any ideas what I should declare `orgIntent` as?

**Update**

Thanks to @zapl I realised the generic type parameter on the method definition was a complete red herring.

This compiles, but presumably means I could somehow have an `Intent` that is genericised to have any old nonsense as the first generic type?

```
private DirectedAcyclicGraph<Intent<?, ? extends Resolution>, DefaultEdge> buildGraph(Declaration declaration) throws CycleFoundException
{
    DirectedAcyclicGraph<Intent<?, ? extends Resolution>, DefaultEdge> dag = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    OrgIntent orgIntent = new OrgIntent("some name");
    dag.addVertex(orgIntent);
```

Comment: `<OrgIntent, IdentifiableResolution>`?I don't see how it would be related  to whatever `I` and `R` are in your code

Comment: `I` is an implementation of `Intent`, and `R` is an implementation of Resolution`. `OrgIntent` implements `Intent<OrgIntent, IdentifiableResolution>`, thus satisfying `Intent<I, R>`.

Comment: In your line where you attempt to construct the `OrgIntent`, does it work if you change it to `OrgIntent<I, R>("some name")` ?

Comment: But the types that substitute I and R in that method don't have to be exactly `OrgIntent` and `IdentifiableResolution`. They can be other incompatible implementations of `Intent` and `Resolution`.

Comment: @JeremyKato Thanks. Nah, that doesn't work, as `OrgIntent` itself is not generic.

Comment: @zapl Thanks. You're right; I want to add various different implementations of `Intent<I, R>` to the `DirectedAcyclicGraph`. The graph should contain any Intent, basically. But I want each Intent to have compile-time safety as to the type of `ResolutionStrategy` passed to it. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is maybe just a bit of `? extends Something` missing in `dag.addVertex()`. But you'll find that it's not possible to keep a more specialized type on items you put in a container because anything more special than the common container type gets lost as soon as you have no more reference to the item.

Comment: @zapl are you sure that's the case? Library types like `ArrayList` and `HashMap`have no problem storing `Object`.

Comment: What I mean: You can store a `Double` and a `Integer` in a `List<Number>`, but you won't get a `Double` or `Integer` back out. You can only take them as `Number` and then do runtime type checks if you want to figure out which they are. Same for your DAG, you'll probably be unable to use all the nice generic types you have beyond the basic `Intent` and `Resolution`.

Comment: And @EngineerBetter, perhaps making the interfaces into abstract classes instead would help fix the issue too - though it's hard to tell, this is truly a generic hell.

Comment: Ah, in that case @zapl that's true, I see what you mean now

Comment: Thanks for the input, folks. The degree of generic insanity is not lost on me, I realise this is pretty crazy code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like zapl suggests in the comments, generics don't provide strong enough type guarantees to handle the pattern you're describing. In particular because Java generics are non-reified there's no way for the JVM to recover a more specific type (`OrgIntent`) after it's cast to a more general type (`Intent<I, R>`). Since the generic type information is lost at runtime the JVM can only rely on the concrete raw types (`Intent`).

This is the same reason, for example, that you can't define two methods with different generic signatures but the same concrete signature - `foo(List<String>)` and `foo(List<Integer>)` both become simply `foo(List)` at runtime and therefore the compiler won't allow you to define two such methods in the same class.

Broadly speaking (and I'm afraid I don't understand your use case well enough to be more precise) the solution is to explicitly associate objects with the desired generic type either via the associated [`Class` object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) or a [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken). For example you might be able to get the following signature to work:

```
R resolve(Class<I> intentClass, I intent);
```

The advice offered in [Effective Java Item 29: Consider typesafe heterogeneous containers](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA142&ots=yZIjQin1O-&dq=Typesafe%20Heterogeneous%20Containers&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=Typesafe%20Heterogeneous%20Containers&f=false) also ought to be helpful:

> Sometimes, however, you need more flexibility [than a fixed number of type parameters].... The idea is to parameterize the key instead of the container. Then present the parameterized key to the container to insert or retrieve a value. The generic type system is used to guarantee that the type of the value agrees with its key.
>
> ...
>
> Java's type system is not powerful enough to express [the type relationship between keys and values]. But we know that it’s true, and we take advantage of it when it comes time to retrieve a favorite.